# Authenticate user on constructor

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I want to perform the authentication by token in any url. This authentication is called before the routes and the token is stored in the users table (field `token`).

When accessing the URL `mysite.com/backend/?token=XXX&anyparam=any`, if the token is valid, the user should be redirected to `mysite.com/backend/?anyparam=any`.

I'm tryint to perform the authentication on the constructor of a Controller, so if the URL has a valid token (that matches the token of a user), the user should be authenticated.

```
public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    // url with token
    if($request->has('token')) {
        $new_url = $request->url() . '/?' . http_build_query($request->except(['token']));

        $user = User::where('token', $request->input('token'))->first();

        Auth::login($user);
        //dd(Auth::user()); // says the user is authenticated
        return redirect($new_url)->send();
    }
}
```

However, after the redirect, the user is no longer authenticated.

What am I missing?

Also, the process of generating the tokens has nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: `__constructs` don't have return values. They always return `void`. With that said, since you're using a token to auth the user, I can only assume you're also using some package to take care of the token generation. If that's the case, more info is needed.

Comment: Can you describe for what reason do you need authenticate in construct? Probably, there is another solution

Comment: @Andrew check edited question.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that the best solution is to use a middleware. If, for some reason, you want that to be part of the `__construct`, you can call the middleware from the controller as stated on [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#protecting-routes).

So, your controller would be something like:

```
public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

And the Auth middleware (class `Authenticate`) would have something like:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if($request->has('token')) {
        $new_url = $request->url() . '/?' . http_build_query($request->except(['token']));
        $user = User::where('token', $request->input('token'))->first();

        if (is_object($user)) {
            Auth::login($user);

            return redirect()->to($new_url);
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

If you don't want to mess with `auth` you can always create [another middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#defining-middleware).